# How to Compare two dates in LINQ in Entity Framework in .NET 5

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, dbfunctions

```
using DbFunctions = System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions;
```

Using the above namespace I tried below ways but nothing worked.
This code is throwing an exception which states...

```
public async Task<int> SomeFunction(){
var count = await _context.Drives.CountAsync(c => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(c.CreatedOn) == DateTime.Today);

var count1 = await _context.Drives.Where(c => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(c.CreatedOn) == DateTime.Today).CountAsync();

var data =  _context.Drives.Where(c => !c.IsDeleted).ToList();

//This throw an exception 
// "This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities."
var count2 = data.Count(x=> DbFunctions.TruncateTime(c.CreatedOn) == DateTime.Today)
}
```

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet().Where(d => DbFunctions.TruncateTime((Nullable)d.CreatedOn) == (Nullable)DateTime.Today)' could not be translated

Can someone help me out how can I compare two dates (only date not with time) in LINQ and Entity Framework?

Comment: Which EF version? Which Data Provider?

Comment: EF 6 and IQueryable @SvyatoslavDanyliv

Comment: `IQueryable` is not data provider. SQL Server, SQLite, etc. is data provider.

Comment: `DbFunctions.TruncateTime` should not work for InMemory provider.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you are applying `DbFunctions.TruncateTime` to `data`.
`data` is of type `List<Drive>` on not `IQueryable<Drive>`, because you already called `ToList()`.
So you `Count` would be evaluated in memory and not on the database.

If that is really, what you want, then you can just use it like this:

```
var count2 = data.Count(x=> x.CreatedOn.Day == DateTime.Today);
```

If you want to invoke your query on the database, then you can use

```
var count2 = _context.Drives.Count(x=> !x.IsDeleted && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.CreatedOn) == DateTime.Today);
```

Depending on the versions and database, you are using, solution 1 may also work on the database

```
var count2 = _context.Drives.Count(x=> !x.IsDeleted && c.CreatedOn.Day == DateTime.Today);
```

Another solution would be to just use a time range, which will definetily work on the database and in memory

```
var start = DateTime.Today;
var end = start.AddDays(1);

var count2InMemory = data.Count(x => x.CreatedOn >= start && x.CreatedOn < end);
var count2InDatabase = _context.Drives.Count(x=> !x.IsDeleted && x.CreatedOn >= start && x.CreatedOn < end);
```

A final side-note:
You should use `async` and `await` when you query the database.

Comment: `var count2 = _context.Drives.Count(x=> !x.IsDeleted && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.CreatedOn) == DateTime.Today);` 
This code is throwing an exception that I mentioned above. I have already tried this and others are for InMemory data. (CreatedOn.Date == DateTime.Today is also not working)